# Prove that $p^j q^i$ cannot be a perfect number for $p, q$ odd, distinct primes.

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers

Define $\sigma(m) = \sum$ d : d|n.  Prove that $p^j$$q^i$ cannot be a perfect number for $p, q$ odd, distinct primes.

Attempt at Solution: I have shown that $p^k$ can never be a perfect number, and im trying to use the multiplicative property of $\sigma$ to generalize to $p^j$$q^i$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have 
$$\sigma(p^jq^i)=\sigma(p^j)\sigma(q^i)=\frac{p^{j+1}-1}{p-1}\cdot \frac{q^{i+1}-1}{q-1}\lt \frac{p^{j+1}q^{i+1}}{(p-1)(q-1)}=p^jq^i \frac{p}{p-1}\cdot \frac{q}{q-1}.$$
Without loss of generality we can assume that $p\lt q$. Note that $\frac{p}{p-1}\le \frac{3}{2}$ and $\frac{q}{q-1}\le \frac{5}{4}$. It follows that $\frac{p}{p-1}\cdot \frac{q}{q-1}\le \frac{15}{8}\lt 2$. We conclude that $p^jq^i$ is deficient, and in particular cannot be perfect.

Comment: I've been fiddling around with the geometric series!  But I couldn't see that the product was less than 15/8.  Would you be able to clarify why that's true?

p/p-1 is less than 3/2?  Is it becauseas p approaches infinity, the fraction approaches 1?  Thus the larger p is, the smaller the residue is?

Comment: Yes, you have described the reason. A more mechanical way of seeing it is to note that $\frac{p}{p-1}=\frac{p-1+1}{p-1}=1+\frac{1}{p-1}$, It is clear that $\frac{1}{p-1}$ decreases as $p$ increases. So the two largest values of $1+\frac{1}{p-1}$, for odd primes $p$, are at $p=3$ and $p=5$.